# Debug and fix the issue in the for Loop syntax in Batch Files other than using echo

Tags: batch-file

I am new to windows batch files and I am trying to write a script which would generate builds depending on the Id's parsed from a file but with two different flags every time i.e. two different images.

```
...
...
...
...
set /A count=1
...
...
...
...
goto: recursive_function
  ...
  ...
  ...
  echo ...............................................
  for /L %%G IN (1,1,2) DO ( echo ............................................. 
  echo G
      if %count%==1 (
          set Build_low=01AD
          set Build_high=1FAE
      )
      if %count%==2(
         set Build_low=01FF
         set Build_high=1FAA
      )

  ...
  ...
  ...
  ...
  )
```

I am getting a syntax error at the for loop initialization I guess.

I tried doing a >for /?
and followed the syntax but still couldn't figure out the issue.

I am trying to learn this loop twice at first and once successful I'll extend this to implement the parsing of the files.

Comment: It looks as though you may want to increment `%count%`, perhaps by using `Set /A count+=1`. However if that was the intention you would also need to use delayed expansion as well.

Comment: Can't you spot the difference in the two `if` blocks? Type `if /?` to find out which one is correct...

Comment: @Compo Thanks. But that is incremented later in the script with another check. I guess it is breaking at for loop.

Comment: @aschipfl I get it.. must have been a typo here but thanks. I didn't knew about the '/?' thing!!!!

Comment: @aschipfl and as I said "I am new to windows batch files...." and yes thanks for pointing that out as before I did not have the understanding that it the spacing here would make a difference as in the other programming languages.

Comment: @ani, I'm still not understanding from the snippet you've posted because count can only be `1`, _(because you've already used `set /A count=1`, which should technically read `Set "count=1"`)_. `If %count%==%%G` would make more sense, but in that case `set /A count=1` would only be a placeholder otherwise `%Build_low%` would always be `01FF` and `%Build_high%` would always be `1FAA` upon completion of the `For` loop.

Comment: @Compo To avoid the confusion:
Consider `set /A count=1' as an initializer used in the early part f the script which is used here w/o change in between. This forloop is part of a go-to function so the condition.

Comment: @ani, if code isn't working after making the change suggested in the only answer and aschipfl's comment, then you've little choice but to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56050183/edit) to expand upon your code sufficiently that we can replicate your issue, and help you with a solution.

Answer (score 2):

`==2(` should be `==2 (`.

The space is significant

Comment: Thanks. I fixed that. I am doing multiple trial and errors.. this might have happened while making a change. I am getting a syntax error for the 'for loop as the echo things works right before it and not after.

Comment: I can understand and I am not comfortable posting the entire thing as well. Let me make changes and may be I can post then.

Meanwhile, do you confirm that there is no Syntax error in the for-loop part

Comment: There's no error in the `for` loop as far as you've published it. If you were to write the remainder of the `for` loop as a subroutine, you could `call` it and progressively debug the routine.